# Why does calling SetDataBinding on a VSTO ListObject result in an exception (0x800A03EC) at runtime?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I am attempting to build a `DataTable` based on an Excel `ListObject` at runtime from a VSTO add-in. The basic approach is I have a UDF that watches for a reference to the `ListObject`, and on encountering it, essentially takes ownership of that object by building a corresponding strongly typed `DataTable`, binding the table to the `ListObject`, and operating on the table. The result *should* be that I can then operate on the `DataTable` in the future without first confirming if it actually reflects the data in Excel, and the user can tweak values as needed.

What I'm finding is that, the below code is throwing an exception with code 0x800A03EC (and no explanation) on the call to `SetDataBinding`. Does anyone know why this is?

```
// Using statements mapping the interop namespace to Excel, and the VSTO one (Excel.Tools) to VSTO.

// Called from an ExcelDNA addin...
public object MyUDF(params object args[])
{
    if (!_DataDict.ContainsKey(args[0]))
    {

        Excel.ListObject listObject = FindListObject(args[0]); // Finds the appropriate object
        VSTO.ListObject vstoListObject = Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(listObject);
        DataTable data = ReadListObjectToTable(listObject);
        vstoListObject.SetDataBinding(data); // Exception Here
        _DataDict.Add(args[0], data);
    }

    // Retrieve data by key and operate on it.
}
```

If I skip data binding, then everything works, but the data stays unbound: changes made in the worksheet aren't reflected in the table. If I insist on binding, then, I get an Exception. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`SetDataBinding` seems to make calls against Excel that are forbidden *during* the process of executing a calculation (but perfectly legal at other times).

Therefore, instead of performing the binding during the calculation, use a self-detaching event on `Application.SheetSelectionChange`, and perform the binding there. I.e.

```
Excel.AppEvents_SheetSelectionChangeEventHandler bindToData = null;
bindToData = 
    (s, e) => {
        xlApp.SheetSelectionChange -= bindToData;
        vstoList.SetDataBinding(clone);
    };
xlApp.SheetSelectionChange += bindToData;
```

Result is everything binds up neatly.